# What is the most well representative letter in fonts?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, font-recommendation

Is there such a thing as the most representative letter in fonts, by seeing which we could definitively say that it's one font or another. Is it possible to identify a font by a single character, or possibly by a set of characters? If so, which character (minimal set of characters) would be the most representative?

Comment: I've seen people use the word "Handgloves".

Comment: Thank you @Wolff! Do you know of there is any scientifically proven way to confirm that "Handgloves" is the best word?

Comment: I don't know about "scientifically". If I knew more I would post a proper answer. Maybe someone else can explain. No subset of characters will ever be able to show *all* of a font's characteristics, but it's about leaving out letters which often have similar shapes. `ages` can be quite unique. `n` can be similar to `muh`, `d` to `bq`, `l` to `i`, `o` to `c`, `v` to `w`.

Comment: This entirely depends on the language you want to use, since obviously there are different features in the font sections for different languages.

Comment: @Wolff - Totally off-topic, but quite funny because "handgloves" isn't actually a word in English. It seems to be a failed attempt to translate the German word "handschuhe" literally hand-shoes. The word in English is just "gloves".  LOL;)

Comment: @BillyKerr. Haha. Yeah, I thought about it just after posting. We use "Handgloves" here in Denmark as well. But not "footsock" or "headhat".

Comment: I've also seen "Foxglove" used or "Zygote". Then of course there's "The quick brown fox jumped..."